# Error:cannot reshape array of size 65536 into shape (2,227)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a data and I read it with the code below.

```
 file_path0='C:\\Users\\ASUS\\Downloads\\A03VM.bin'
 def read_file():
     data=np.fromfile(file_path0,np.float64)
     print(data)
     return data
```

then I want to turn it into two dimensions. And I run the code below:

```
data=np.reshape(data, (2,227))
```

but I get this error:

> cannot reshape array of size 65536 into shape (2,227)

what can I do? what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that you have 65536  elements and you try to reshape to an array with 2*227 elements

Comment: @DavidS ok that's right. how can I take this data into two dimensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to reshape using the parameter `-1` meaning that you will let `numpy` infer the right dimensions.

So if you want to reshape it that the first dimension is `2` you should do the following:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.zeros((65536,))
print(x.shape)  # (65536,)
x_reshaped = np.reshape(x, (2, -1))
print(x_reshaped .shape)  # (2, 32768)
```

If you want the first dimension to be infered you need to do the following:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.zeros((65536,))
print(x.shape)  # (65536,)
x_reshaped = np.reshape(x, (-1, 256))
print(x_reshaped .shape)  # (256, 256)
```

Notice that in the second case `227` wont work because *65536/227* is not an integer value thus `numpy` wont be able to infer it.

You can refer to the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

> The new shape should be compatible with the original shape. If an
> integer, then the result will be a 1-D array of that length. One shape
> dimension can be -1. In this case, the value is inferred from the
> length of the array and remaining dimensions.

Comment: .I did it and my problem was solved.just in the first code x=np.zeros((65536,))  zero all drives.I run the code without that line...thanks